# If $(X_n)$ is a martingale, prove that $(X_{n\wedge N})_n$ is a martingale, where $N$ is a stoping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a martingale w.r.t. the filtration $(\mathcal F_n)$. Let $N$ a stopping time on $\mathbb N$. Prove that $(X_{N\wedge n})_n$ is a martingale w.r.t. $(\mathcal F_n)$.

**Attempts**

I have to prove that $$\mathbb E[X_{N\wedge (n+1)}\mid \mathcal F_n]=X_{N\wedge n}.$$

So let $F\in \mathcal F_n$. Then, $$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X_{N\wedge (n+1)}\mid \mathcal F_n]\boldsymbol 1_F]=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_F X_{N\wedge (n+1)}]=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_{N\wedge (n+1)}\mid N=p]\mathbb P\{N=p\}.$$

**Q1)** Is it true that $$\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_{N\wedge (n+1)}\mid N=p]=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_{p\wedge (n+1)}]\ \  ?$$

If yes, then $$\sum_{p=0}^\infty\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_{N\wedge (n+1)}\mid N=p]\mathbb P\{N=p\}=\sum_{o=0}^\infty \mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_{p\nabla (n+1)}]\mathbb P\{N=p\}=\sum_{p=0}^n\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_p]\mathbb P\{N=p\}+\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_{n+1}]\mathbb P\{N=p\}.$$
Since $(X_n)$ is a martingale, $$\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_{n+1}]=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_F\mathbb E[X_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n]]=\mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_FX_n]$$

**Q2)** How can I continue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that 
$$
\begin{aligned}
E(X_{N\wedge n+1}| \mathcal F_n) &= E(X_{N} 1_{N\leq n}+X_{n+1} 1_{N\geq n+1}| \mathcal F_n)\\
&= 1_{N\leq n} E(X_{N} | \mathcal F_n) + 1_{N\geq n+1}E(X_{n+1}| \mathcal F_n)\\
&= 1_{N\leq n} X_N + 1_{N\geq n+1}X_n\\
&= X_{N\wedge n}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: In your second-to-last line, the first term should be $1_{N\leq n}X_N,$ which is easy to see if you note $1_{N\leq n}X_N \in \mathcal{F}_n$ in the first line.

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks for catching the typo !

Comment: as the OP asked, does $\mathbb E[X_N\mid N=p]=\mathbb E[X_p\mid N=p]$ or $\mathbb E[X_N\mid N=p]=\mathbb E[X_p]$ ? I would say yes, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user659895 $\mathbb E[X_N\mid N=p]=\mathbb E[X_p\mid N=p]$ holds when $N$ and the $X_i$ are independent, otherwise I don't think it's true (write the expectations in terms of integrals w.r.t the appropriate regular conditional distributions).

Comment: If $X_i$ and $N$ are independents, $\mathbb E[X_p\mid N=p]=\int_{\mathbb R}xf_{X_p\mid N=p}(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb R}xf_{X_p}(x)dx=\mathbb E[X_p]$. But now, what would be $\mathbb E[X_N\mid N=p]$ ? Is it $\int_{\mathbb R}xf_{X_N|N=p}(x)dx$ ? If yes, what is $f_{X_N|N=p}(x)$ ? the fact that $N$ is a r.v., I don't see what could be $f_{X_N}$ or $f_{X_N|N=p}$. thank you.

Comment: @user659895 Let $Y=(X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ and note that $$E(X_N|N=p) = E(\sum_k X_k 1_{N=k}|N=p) = \int \sum_k x_k 1_{N=k}dP_{Y|N=p} (x)= \int x_p dP_{Y|N=p} (x)$$ while
$$ 
E(X_p|N=p) = \int x_p dP_{X_p|N=p} (x_p)
$$
The problem is that the final integrals may not be equal (they are when the $X_i$ and $N$ are independent).

Answer (score 0):

My favourite proof relies on the fact that $M_{N \wedge n} - M_{N \wedge (n-1)} = \mathbb{1}_{N \geq n} (M_n - M_{n-1})$. Then, note that $\{ N \geq n \} = \{ N  \leq n-1\}^c \in \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$. Therefore, $\mathbb{1}_{N \geq n}$ is a predictable process so:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[M_{N \wedge n} - M_{N \wedge (n-1)} | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} \right] = \mathbb{1}_{N \geq n}\mathbb{E}\left[M_{n} - M_{n-1} | \mathcal{F}_{n-1} \right]=0.
\end{equation}